# Is there an ASP.NET Identity Active Directory Provider (or am I thinking of this wrong)

Tags: authentication, active-directory, asp.net-identity-2

I am developing an Angular + ASP.NET Web API application and would like to use ASP.NET Identity.  The customer uses Active Directory and would like to log in to the application using their AD credentials. On IE "inside" the network, the app should use the credentials of the current user (it will be in the intranet zone).  On non-IE browsers or outside the network, the customer would like a login page (as opposed to a NTLM or Basic Auth prompt for credentials).

Given all that, I've landed on writing a custom Identity IUserStore that handles authenticating against LDAP, similar to the ActiveDirectoryMembershipProvider, but for Identity.  Is there an existing implementation for Identity against AD?  The customer does not have ADFS configured, but should I be pushing them toward that instead of rolling my own provider?

Comment: Would you mind posting your customer IUserStore or sharing it on a site like GitHub?

Comment: Sorry - I decided a custom IUserStore was too involved and scrapped that concept.